# How do calculate a determinant of an large matrix without getting an overflow?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matrix, determinants

Good morning!

I have an nxn-Matrix with n large enough to give me an overflow.

I tried to fix this problem the mathematical way and it worked for small n but now I get an overflow from the Exponent.

To explain it better here the code:

```py
    # create a quadratic Matrix matrix with shape 500x500
    matrix = [[ 1.03796037 -0.00898546 -0.00410423 ... -0.0453022   0.02608995
      -0.01146299]
     ...

     [-0.01146299 -0.04572196  0.07370042 ...  0.03203931  0.07298667
       0.98693473]]

    # calculate the mean of matrix
    mean = matrix.mean()
    # calculate n
    n = matrix.shape[0]
    # divide the mean from the matrix and calculate the determinant 
    determinant = np.linalg.det(matrix/mean)
    # use now det(c*M) = c^n*det(M)
    solution = mean**n*determinant

    >>>> inf
```

This method works to prevent the overflow from the `np.linalg.det()` function but the calculation of the power `mean**n` gives an overflow and I have no idea how to solve this. The mean is btw a float and n a int
Can you help here? Please only in Python or numpy.

Comment: Maybe look at this post on how to handle large numbers => https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/128589/how-to-handle-large-numbers

Comment: @VictorDeleau Hello Victor. I saw this question before I created this one, because I could not relate the solution there to my problem. Here we have a float ** large int.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You would address it by calling "`numpy.linalg.slogdet`" instead of "`numpy.linalg.det`". As it has been pointed out [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.slogdet.html)

> **slogdet** can be used whenever the **det** has led to overflowing/underflowing.

Hope it works.